# Can a aspx page be loaded into a Silverlight Control?

Tags: .net, silverlight

Forgeive me if this is a dumb question, im very new to SL, just ordered 3 books which i should have tomorrow - but i cant stop thinking of the 'is it possible' stuff.

Heres what i would LOVE to do, dont know if it possible:

Have a SL control on a page that loads a passed in url or aspx (like the browser control for winforms) - the reason i would like this is the ability to have a page visible and use zooming/panning to view various parts of the page - this may sound stupid, but it would allow users to view/modify elements w/o having to open a sep window, iframe, etc to view it (and the zoom/pan would be bad ass)

Thanks in advance, please dont hate - if this is that stupid of an idea i'll wait to post again until i read my books.

BTW, WPF, etc is not an option, this has to be web based :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is No.  There is no control within Silverlight which allows you to host some kind of WebBrowser control.  I'm not sure what you would hope to gain bearing in mind most current browsers have a zoom facility of their own.

Comment: I know it sounds dumb, but would useful in my case.  I know i can use browser zoom controls, but cant guarantee what browser will be used, whereas if silverlight was used i'd be golden (if it was capable) ... you cant load a page in an iframe and zoom 25% so that you can view then entire page in a small area.

Comment: @shcmoopy: Fair enough but SL isn't going to help you here.

Answer (score -1):

For the record "silverlight" is not the web nor is it well supported. At any rate you can load HTML into Silverlight using a html text block. Given how bad they are at writing browsers though I wouldn't hold out much hope of its rendering engine being any better, or less error-prone, than IE's.

Anyway, there's several things you can do:

Anyway, info [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2007/09/10/bringing-a-bit-of-html-to-silverlight-htmltextblock-makes-rich-text-display-easy.aspx) (htmltextblock) [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/02/15/using-windowless-silverlight-controls-to-blend-html-and-silverlight-elements.aspx) and [here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2007/10/03/integrating-silverlight-and-html-dom.aspx)

UPDATE: On further reading htmltextblock is some kind of user extension, and a pretty limited one at that. It doesn't look like zooming/panning rich HTML is possible.

Comment: -1 a) this not actually an answer. b) whats the point of using some sensible question as a platform to slate IE.  Plenty of other places inside and outside SO for well reasoned MS bashing.

Comment: you jumped on the answer too soon i'm afraid. at any rate i have enough experience with html in flash and IE to know this isn't going to be pretty.

Comment: Im giving you an upvote simply cause of your screen name: SpliFF ... in the future dont reply to my posts high ;-)